# HPE ProLiant XL270d Gen9 - Ubuntu remote login into shell after Installation

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant, remote-access, ilo, hpe

I have installed ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64 on a HPE ProLiant XL270d Gen9. The installation is fine, it is booting correctly.

Since I'm not located nearby the data center, therefore, I installed the operating system via iLO remote console (iLO->Remote Console -> Java web start) using the latest Chrome version on MacOS. After booting and login into the operating system, the remote console shuts down automatically.

I also activated the iLO Advanced License (Free Trial).

Since SSH-Server is not yet installed on Ubuntu I have no possibility to login into Ubuntu. I think that is a standard problem. However, I do not know how to resolve it.

---

Resolved see below.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The problem was that the IP of iLO IP was the same as for the installed operating system. This is the reason why the remote console was closed immediately after the OS was started.

Learning: Never give our operating system the same IP as iLO.

Answer (score 0):

One of the oft-overlooked iLO features is a virtual serial port.  If you configure Linux to redirect one of the consoles to the virtual serial port, you can then access it by SSHing into iLO.  This should give you console access and enable you to set up SSH and connect to the server directly.

The iLO user's manual has information about how to set this up (online copy [here](http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/398445/hp-integrated-lights-out-3.html?page=128), albeit for an older iLO version).  You do have to make some config changes on the remote system, but you should be able to do this by booting from whatever media you used to install the OS, dropping to a shell, and changing config files on the server's filesystem.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/830748/how-to-enable-and-use-the-serial-terminal-of-a-hp-microserver-gen9?rq=1) has an answer that includes a fairly thorough walkthrough of the process.